# UICollectionViewCell's subview absolute frame

Tags: swift, uiimageview, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Have been having this issue that I considered to be an easy solve, but spent a lot of time cracking it with no result.

So, I have a **UIViewController** with **UICollectionView** in it. This collection is padded 75 px from the top and has cells with pretty simple setup - just 1 **UIImageView** set to fit the size of the container. Everything is made with **AutoLayout**.

My task is to make **UIImageView** go full screen on tap. What I am doing is making a temporary **UIImageView** and add to the hierarchy of **UIViewController** view.

The problem I am facing is I can't get the absolute frame of **UIImageView** in the cell I tap.

I tried various ways to calculate the frame, my most recent try is

```
var rect = cell.imageView.superview!.convertRect(cell.imageView.frame, toView: self.view)
```

However, it returns result that seems to be ignoring the collection view top constraint.

**Update**:

It turns out my problem was in the wrong way I was acquiring the cell from collection view. Instead of:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UIImageCollectionViewCell
```

I was getting cell with

```
let cell = self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! UIImageCollectionViewCell
```

Which obviously resulted in creating a new cell with the wrong frame. My bad, late night coding is not the best thing sometimes. Thanks to [Arun Ammannaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5746309/arun-ammannaya) for the quick example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what i tried, works as expected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("aaa", forIndexPath: indexPath)
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

@IBAction func frame(sender: AnyObject) {

    print(String(sender.frame))

    let rect = sender.superview??.convertRect(sender.frame, toView: self.view)

    print(String(rect))

    let addedView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(addedView)
    addedView.frame = rect!

    addedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
}
```

}

Story board looks like:

[image: Storybord]

Output is looks like:

[image: Output]